# What do you call the movement of monkeys from one branch of tree to another?

Tags: word-request

Oftentimes monkeys move or jump from one tree to another using their hands and feet. I am okay with calling it "jumping" but I wonder if there is a name for the specific kind of movement. Does that have a name?

Comment: You could also say they *leap* from tree to tree. Could you give an example sentence showing how you would like to use the word? You could use "jump" where you want the word to be.

Comment: Monkeys swing through the trees. Only Anthropologists brachiate.

Comment: Doesn't that depend on the type or movement?

Monkeys drop, "fly" or fling themselves, jump, leap or spring from branch to branch.

How is that a "specific kind of movement"?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That is called ***brachiation*** and they're ***[brachiating](https://www.lexico.com/definition/brachiate)*** or simply ***[swinging](https://www.lexico.com/definition/swing)***.

*Swinging* is much more predominant than *brachiating*. *Brachiating* is more likely to be used by Primatologists.

> **[Brachiation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brachiation)** or **arm swinging**, is a form of arboreal locomotion in which primates swing from tree limb to tree limb using only their arms. [Wikipedia]

Comment: Note that this is a fairly obscure word that wouldn't be familiar to most native speakers who are not primatologists.

Comment: The only place I've ever heard the word "Brachiation" was in a college-level anthropology class...

Comment: "Brachiation" is used as a term in robotic locomotion as well.

Comment: @CanadianYankee I don't think it's that obscure. I'm not a primatologist, and this answer was my first thought when I saw this question.

Comment: People are allowed to be happy when they see/learn terms like this. But this is code switching. The OP might have said: what is the technical name for this.

Comment: Even if technically correct, this is very rarely the term that native English speakers would want to use. No one's going to say "I saw a monkey brachiating through the trees from my hotel window when I was on holiday" (except maybe a primatologist talking to another primatologist). This would be a much better answer if it made clear the difference in usage between 'brachiating' and 'swinging'.

Answer (score 14):

- Monkeys typically swing from branch to branch.

It is important to say from branch to branch or from tree to tree or from x to y.

They do not jump as jumping involves the feet, not the arms, which is what monkeys use to propel themselves.

Answer (score -2):

'Clamber' or 'clambering' is about perfect:
VERB
climb, move, or get in or out of something in an awkward and laborious way, typically using both hands and feet.

Comment: Welcome to ELL! What do you mean "Clamber' or 'clambering' is about perfect"?

Comment: Monkeys do not usually move about in an "awkward and laborious" way.

Answer (score -3):

How about "migrating" if it is a group

Comment: Welcome to English Language Learners! While this may be correct, we like our answers to be backed up by references. You can [edit] your answer to include one (e.g. an online dictionary). See the Help Center article [answer]. In particular, monkeys "migrating" implies movement but usually on the ground and longer distances.